# what is "?" in ruby

Tags: ruby

Ruby 1.9

```
irb(main):001:0> ?c
=> "c"
```

Ruby 1.8.6

```
 irb(main):001:0> ?c
 => 99
```

what does "?" mean ?

Comment: I believe ?a behaives in the same way as "a"[0]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It denotes a "character". In ruby 1.8, this was represented by the ascii-code of the character. In Ruby 1.9, it's a single-character `String`.

Answer (score 7):

In 1.8 they give you the ASCII value of a character, in 1.9 they are character literals:

```
>> RUBY_VERSION #=> "1.8.7"
>> ?a #=> 97 
>> RUBY_VERSION #=> "1.9.2"
>> ?a #=> "a"
>> *[?a..?c] #=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > ?c == "c"
 => true
```